# Change the String variable via firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, setstate

How do I obtain the `document.documentID` in firebase for a String?

When I print the `document.documentID` it works fine, I presume I need a `Future` or something, but could use some help changing my String field `subUserID` to the `document.documentID`?

```
onPressed: () async {
      print(document.documentID);
      setState(() {
        subUserID = document.documentID;
      });
      _toggleBackdropPanelVisibility();
    },
```

Actual result = prints the `documentID` but doesn't change the state of the String.

Further information on code:

This is my Widget to get the list of users that I have on the cloud firebase store which works fine;

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Container(
   child: StreamBuilder(
     stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
     builder: (context, snapshot) {
       if (!snapshot.hasData) {
         return Center(
           child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
         );
       } else {
         return ListView.builder(
           physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(
               parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
           padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
               vertical: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top + kToolbarHeight),
           itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
               buildUsers(context, snapshot.data.documents[index]),
           itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
         );
       }
     },
   ),
 );
}
```

In the buildUsers function i have the following:

```
 Widget buildUsers(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
   return FlatButton(
      child: ///
      onPressed: widget.onPressed
      ///
 }
```

I pass the widget.onPressed to the top build function where I want to change the String for subUserID to what I have on tap which will show the list of messages per the Current User and the subUserID.

The current implementation of the onPressed is at the top of the screen.

I can get the string to work if I were to navigate to the new screen but I can't get it to work when I don't navigate to a new screen - as I wanted a backdrop implementation the navigator doesn't really help.

For my buildMessages widget the idea is to show the messages from the user-subUserID messages.

Comment: Without more context it's hard to identify the issue. `setState`'s syntax is fine, so If `print` is showing the correct value, it should have worked. How are you using `subUserID`? Why do you think it was not changed?

Comment: Please provide full context of your widget. There's no way of telling where the error is from just this snippet. And you don't need to make the `onPressed` function `async` since you're not awaiting or returning anything.

Comment: Fixed - the `setState` did work but the string didn't pass correctly to another widget so I had to include all in the same widget. Thanks